# Trump ban - Libyan born Indian Citizen

Tags: usa

Is the Trump travel ban only limited to citizens/nationals of the seven countries or even to people born in those countries? I was born in Libya, relocated to India when I was 4. We now live in HKG, but hold an Indian Passport. Am planning to visit family in the first week of March on a visitor visa issued 8 years ago. This is my first trip to the US. Am I likely to encounter trouble at the immigration desk?

Comment: Note that the other question is about Yemen, but it doesn't really matter